# Trouble getting simple Typescript file to run

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm

I started [this Typescript](https://fullstackopen.com/en/part9/first_steps_with_type_script#setting-things-up) course and the steps to set everything up are quite straightforward. I created a new directory, ran `npm init`, then `npm install --save-dev ts-node typescript`. I added a script to my package.json as follows like the course suggests

```
PACKAGE.JSON:
{
  "name": "part9",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "ts-node": "ts-node"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "ts-node": "^10.2.1",
    "typescript": "^4.3.5"
  }
}
```

and created a *multiplier.ts* file as follows:

```
const multiplicator = (a, b, printText) => {
  console.log(printText, a * b);
};

multiplicator(2, 4, "Multiplied numbers 2 and 4, the result is:");
```

at this point, the course says to run the script `npm run ts-node -- multiplier.ts` but when I do that, my terminal blows up with errors. I spent an hour installing several packages that other stackoverflow users suggested but nothing works and the error message isn't exactly clear what is wrong to a beginner. Can someone help me? This is the error below. I am using Windows 10 if that makes a difference.

```
> part9@1.0.0 ts-node C:\Users\user\Documents\Documents\Projects\_Courses\FullStackOpen\part9
> ts-node "multiplier.ts"

C:\Users\user\Documents\Documents\Projects\_Courses\FullStackOpen\part9\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:692
    return new TSError(diagnosticText, diagnosticCodes);
           ^
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
multiplier.ts:1:24 - error TS7006: Parameter 'a' implicitly has an 'any' type.

1 const multiplicator = (a, b, printText) => {
                         ~
multiplier.ts:1:27 - error TS7006: Parameter 'b' implicitly has an 'any' type.

1 const multiplicator = (a, b, printText) => {
                            ~
multiplier.ts:1:30 - error TS7006: Parameter 'printText' implicitly has an 'any' type.

1 const multiplicator = (a, b, printText) => {
                               ~~~~~~~~~
multiplier.ts:2:3 - error TS2584: Cannot find name 'console'. Do you need to change your target library? Try 
changing the 'lib' compiler option to include 'dom'.

2   console.log(printText, a * b);
    ~~~~~~~

    at createTSError (C:\Users\user\Documents\Documents\Projects\_Courses\FullStackOpen\part9\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:692:12)
    at reportTSError (C:\Users\user\Documents\Documents\Projects\_Courses\FullStackOpen\part9\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:696:19)
    at getOutput (C:\Users\user\Documents\Documents\Projects\_Courses\FullStackOpen\part9\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:883:36)
    at Object.compile (C:\Users\user\Documents\Documents\Projects\_Courses\FullStackOpen\part9\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:1185:30)
    at Module.m._compile (C:\Users\user\Documents\Documents\Projects\_Courses\FullStackOpen\part9\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:1309:30)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (C:\Users\user\Documents\Documents\Projects\_Courses\FullStackOpen\part9\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:1313:12)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12) {
  diagnosticText: "\x1B[96mmultiplier.ts\x1B[0m:\x1B[93m1\x1B[0m:\x1B[93m24\x1B[0m - \x1B[91merror\x1B[0m\x1B[90m TS7006: \x1B[0mParameter 'a' implicitly has an 'any' type.\r\n" +
    '\r\n' +
    '\x1B[7m1\x1B[0m const multiplicator = (a, b, printText) => {\r\n' +
    '\x1B[7m \x1B[0m \x1B[91m                       ~\x1B[0m\r\n' +
    "\x1B[96mmultiplier.ts\x1B[0m:\x1B[93m1\x1B[0m:\x1B[93m27\x1B[0m - \x1B[91merror\x1B[0m\x1B[90m TS7006: \x1B[0mParameter 'b' implicitly has an 'any' type.\r\n" +
    '\r\n' +
    '\x1B[7m1\x1B[0m const multiplicator = (a, b, printText) => {\r\n' +
    '\x1B[7m \x1B[0m \x1B[91m                          ~\x1B[0m\r\n' +
    "\x1B[96mmultiplier.ts\x1B[0m:\x1B[93m1\x1B[0m:\x1B[93m30\x1B[0m - \x1B[91merror\x1B[0m\x1B[90m TS7006: \x1B[0mParameter 'printText' implicitly has an 'any' type.\r\n" +
    '\r\n' +
    '\x1B[7m1\x1B[0m const multiplicator = (a, b, printText) => {\r\n' +
    '\x1B[7m \x1B[0m \x1B[91m                             ~~~~~~~~~\x1B[0m\r\n' +
    "\x1B[96mmultiplier.ts\x1B[0m:\x1B[93m2\x1B[0m:\x1B[93m3\x1B[0m - \x1B[91merror\x1B[0m\x1B[90m TS2584: \x1B[0mCannot find name 'console'. Do you need to change your target library? Try changing the 'lib' compiler option to include 'dom'.\r\n" +
    '\r\n' +
    '\x1B[7m2\x1B[0m   console.log(printText, a * b);\r\n' +
    '\x1B[7m \x1B[0m \x1B[91m  ~~~~~~~\x1B[0m\r\n',
  diagnosticCodes: [ 7006, 7006, 7006, 2584 ]
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! part9@1.0.0 ts-node: `ts-node "multiplier.ts"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the part9@1.0.0 ts-node script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-08-26T00_32_28_752Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those errors are to be expected with an out of the box TS setup. The error `a implicitly has any type` means that you haven't given the param `a` an expected type and it defaults to any.

If you wanted to fix that error you could give the parameters a typing:

```
const multiplicator = (a: number, b: number, printText: string) => {
  console.log(printText, a * b);
};
```

Or alternatively you could tell typescript you don't mind if you have implicit any types in your `tsconfig.json` like so:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false
  }
}
```

If you don't have a tsconfig then you should run `tsc --init` and it'll create a basic one for you.

To fix the error about `console` being not being found, you need to add the DOM lib to your tsconfig

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["DOM"]
  }
}
```

This will give you all the global references for a browser environment such as window, etc. If you're just doing this via commandline you can `npm install @types/node` and that will give you all the node types you need

Answer (score 0):

well you is missing the tsconfig.json let's begin by

### init

to create a new project you need

```sh
$ npm init
```

### dependencies

then in the folder where yow package.json was added run this

```sh
$ npm i -D typescript tslib tsutils ts-node
```

### typescript configuration

now to create a typescript project run this

```sh
$ ./node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc --init
```

#### tsconfig.json

yow tsconfig.josn is where the configuration of typescript will be learn more here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig

### start

to run the program in your case would be like this

```json
{
   "scripts": {
       "start": "ts-node ./path-to-where-yow-file-is"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should install this npm pacage.

```
   npm install --save-dev @types/node
```

And I have changed the file "tsconfig.json", then it will work.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["dom"]
  }
}
```